# Activity Life Cycle Methods and Saving State

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I started reading around about the activity life cycle callbacks and saving state and there are quite a few things I don't understand - I'm writing an android app but I want to ask more general questions than how to do it specifically for the few activities etc I have at the moment, I would like to have a better overall view of how this works!

There are two groups of methods I have seen being used (I have seen one or two others but don't want to confuse myself even further...)

- onPause, onResume etc,
- and then the onSaveInstanceState ones.

What is the difference between them and the circumstances we should be looking to use them? I have seen some questions where a poster is using one of the normal life cycle callbacks, and is told to use onSaveInstanceState instead, so when should we be implementing onPause rather than onSaveInstanceState and so on. Some posts mentioned about methods being used for transient state only, could someone expand on that?

I have seen state being used to mean slightly different things - UI/View state and Activity state, what is the difference between the two?
I am also a bit unsure with what they mean by state, when we are saving state what kind of things are we saving exactly, could anyone give some quick examples (I don't mean actual code)? The android developer guides say that the android system automatically takes care of some of this, so what should we be concerned with? Bundle objects used by onCreate and onSaveInstanceState only store simple values, so what about more complex objects and arrays.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void onPause ()
protected void onSaveInstanceState (Bundle outState)
```

Just by looking at it, [onSaveInstanceState](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29)  has an Bundle you can put your things you need to save in it. And get it back in onCreate(Bundle) or onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle);
Some important lines in the document:

> This method is called before an activity may be killed so that when it
>   comes back some time in the future it can restore its state. Do not
>   confuse this method with activity lifecycle callbacks such as
>   [onPause()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPause%28%29), which is always called when an activity is being placed in
>   the background or on its way to destruction, or onStop() which is
>   called before destruction.

Answer (score 0):

try to use this code to save state

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
  State s = new State(yourTextView.getText().toString());
  outState.putSerializable(State.STATE, s);
  super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
  State s = (State) savedInstanceState.getSerializable(State.STATE);
  yourTextView.setText(s.getYourTextViewText());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Android can destroy your activity or even kill your process at any given time (not likely when it is visible to the user though :-)). When the user navigates back to the activity, the data/info that was shown on the screen before he or she left it should be shown again.

The `onSaveInstanceState` callback allows you to do this.

Most of the Views already do this for you automatically. E.g. the current text in an EditText, the current scroll position of a ListView, etc. are all automatically saved for you.

However, there are some things that are not automatically saved for you. E.g. the current text in a TextView, the (changed) background drawable of a particular View.

Say, you show an error message after a user action fails. The error message is then shown in a `TextField` and this `TextField`'s background becomes red (i'm just making this up here :-)). When the user leaves the activity while this error is shown (e.g. presses Home button), the activity is destroyed, the error message and the red background won't be shown again when the user comes back to the activity.

This is where `onSaveInstanceState` comes to the rescue.
You can save a `String` in there that containts the error message. Then when the activity is re-created, the `Bundle savedInstanceState` of the `onCreate` is not null and you can query it for the error message. If this message is not null/empty, call `setText` on the `TextView` for the error message and make that `TextView`'s background red.

Comment: In the error message example, does it not get saved because it wasn't part of the initial ui added during onCreate? So any changes to the ui because of user interaction (or whatever) doesn't get saved automatically?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Some changes to the ui because of user interaction will get saved automatically (e.g. typing text into an EditText). But calling setText on a TextView won't get saved, and calling setBackgroundxxx() on a View won't get saved either. That's where you can use the saved-instance-state to 'fix' this.